# How to use pandas.DataFrame.mask for NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I want to ignore NaN values in my selected dataframe columns when I want to normalize with [`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html). Column example:

```
0     12.0
1     12.0
2      3.0
3      NaN
4      3.0
5      3.0
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      3.0
9      3.0
10     3.0
11     4.0
12    10.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of function `dropna()`. It will return the same dataframe with rows containing `NaN` deleted.

```
>>> a.dropna()
     0  12.0
0    1    12
1    2     3
3    4     3
4    5     3
7    8     3
8    9     3
9   10     3
10  11     4
11  12    10
```

Comment: Hi, I want to see NaN's as NaN at the end after I do the normalization